# Plan cache behaviour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-internals

Can someone please explain me why the following is no getting cached

```
use AdventureWorks2014
go
DECLARE @id INT=43865
SELECT
sp.[BusinessEntityID]
, so.salesorderid
FROM sales.salesorderheader so JOIN sales.salesperson sp
ON sp.[BusinessEntityID] = so.salespersonid
WHERE so.salesorderid = @id
```

Every time I execute the above query with different parameter, it create an entry in plan cache

by the way, optimize for ad hoc workloads is set

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You're using a local variable, not a parameter. So because this is part of your query text:

```
DECLARE @id INT=43865
```

It gets included as part of the query hash (which converts the query text, including `43865`, to binary), and thus produces a different hash every time you change the text. This is how it will work in a Management Studio query window, but it might be different if you send properly parameterized ad hoc queries from a C# application for example.

You can try changing the database setting `Parameterization` to forced, but this is kind of like killing a mosquito with a bulldozer. Better yet (IMHO), instead of ad hoc SQL, use stored procedures where you pass the value of your local variable `@id` via a proper parameter (or skip the local variable altogether and just pass 43865 directly to the stored procedure parameter).

Kendra Little has written a little bit about this too, and she suggests using #temporary procedures to mimic your actual procedure (e.g. for testing changes without changing the base procedure). But that is only relevant if you already have a stored procedure in the first place:

- [Why You’re Tuning Stored Procedures Wrong (the Problem with Local Variables)](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/)

Comment: Thanks Aaron,

Every time I change the variable value I get the same query_hash "0xDFF8AB3AD70AF28F" and qery_plan_hash "0xB158C10DA5A7FB96"

Thanks

Comment: @user1716729 Regardless of what you may see output from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans, the reason is the same (the variable is not a parameter and is interpreted as part of the query text) and the solution is to use properly parameterized queries (e.g. a stored procedure). This is even easier to demonstrate with things like `SELECT TOP (1) SalesOrderID FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader` vs. `select top (1) salesorderid from sales.salesorderheader` - those are two identical queries, but because case isn't identical, you'll get two different plans (even though the query_hash and query_plan_hash are same).